# How to use preventDefault for triggerHandler?

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, eventtrigger

I have the following code used:

```
$('#selector').triggerHandler('contextmenu');
```

But it (the selector) use it's own js function somewhere and now in my particular case I want to prevent its all other functions.

For eg:

I've the following code use somewhere:

```
<input type="button" onclick="dosomething()" />
```

So, how can I use preventDefault here so that it just run contextmenu?

**Edit:**

To simplify my question, I want to trigger contextmenu on left mouse button click.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("#selector").unbind("click");
$("#selector").removeAttr("onclick");
$('#selector').triggerHandler('contextmenu');
```